# How can i use an array in a Where Clause in Laravel Query Builder?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to use the **array** `$aqui` inside `where` clause, but I don't know how to do it. I know how to put multiple values inside `where` clause, but I don't know about `arrays`.

```
$aqui[1] = 35;
$aqui[2] = 67;
$aqui[3] = 44;
$aqui[4] = 12;
$aqui[5] = 9;
//and goes...

$caraio = DB::connection('mysql')
->table('users')
->select('name')
->where( /* where fields are equal to $aqui */ )
->value('name');
```

Comment: Why not use Eloquent model?

Comment: Because i find it confusing and harder to learn and everything i did until now is using Query Builder.

Comment: That's fine, but you can try. I am saying this because they make your work a lot easier. Otherwise, you have to write raw queries yourself.

Comment: are you looking for `->whereIn('aqui', $aqui)`? (guessing here that the attribute you want to filter by is called `aqui` as well - if not, adjust accordingly

Comment: _Because i find it confusing_ So practice? It’s more conventional to use models in Laravel (and most other web frameworks) rather than manually writing queries all over your application.

Comment: I know, but i'm working on this project, and i can't afford taking several days (maybe weeks, idk) trying to learn how can i replace DB Queries over eloquent models. Maybe in my next project, i go deep into it.

Comment: `User::whereIn("property", $aqui)->pluck("name");`

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```php
$aqui[1] = 35;
$aqui[2] = 67;
$aqui[3] = 44;
$aqui[4] = 12;
$aqui[5] = 9;
//and goes...

$caraio = DB::connection('mysql')
->table('users')
->select('name')
->whereIn('attributeName', $aqui)
->value('name');
```

Obviously you want to replace `attributeName` with the name of the attribute that you want to compare values against.

Read more about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-wherein).

Hope this helps!